# Having trouble setting cookies using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to set a cookie using the value of a select box option. I am using the jquery.cookie.js plugin found at: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#set_state").change(function() {
        var theState = $(this).val();
        $.cookie('set_state', theState, { expires: 5, path: '/' });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="set_state" name="state">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="AL">AL</option>
    <option value="AK">AK</option>
    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
    <option value="AR">AR</option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="CO">CO</option>
    <option value="CT">CT</option>
    <!-- no need to post them all here -->
</select>
</body>
```

If I use an alert box to show the variable `theState`, it works, but I can not get the `$.cookie` function to work... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you're having trouble getting the function "to work", what precisely is going wrong? You mean the cookie isn't being set? Sure? (Check in Firebug/Dragonfly)

Comment: Yes, the cookie is not being set at all, even if I specify a value manually (not using the var).

Comment: Try setting it via native JS. If you're using the $.cookie plugin simply to set cookies, that's probably an unnecessary and frivolous impact on your site's load weight.

Comment: @Utkanos - the cookie plugin is only ~700 bytes when minified at jscompress.com; which is insignificant (unless loaded with a separate request, of course)

Comment: @JohnRobinson - does your browser's JS console happen to display any error?

Comment: @egasimus - fair enough, but I'd still try setting the cookie in native JS just as a means to try to track down where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the complete example for setting cookies using jQuery cookie plugin.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://codebins.com/userUploads/3/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
     <select id="set_state" name="state">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        <option value="AK">AK</option>
        <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
        <option value="AR">AR</option>
        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        <option value="CO">CO</option>
        <option value="CT">CT</option>
        <!-- no need to post them all here -->
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="btncookie" value="get cookie" />
    <input type="button" id="btndelcookie" value="delete cookie" />
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#set_state").change(function() {
       var theState = $(this).val();
       $.cookie('set_state', theState, {
           expires: 5,
           path: '/'
       });
  });
  $("#btncookie").click(function() {
      alert("Your Selected Value from Cookie is : " + $.cookie('set_state'));
  });
  $("#btndelcookie").click(function() {
       $.cookie('set_state', '', {
        expires: -1
       });
       $("#set_state").val("");
       alert('Cookie is deleted now, try to get cookie..!');
   });
});
```

Try above example on codebins: http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpc6